# Where does a thread return after being woken up by a semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

**My understanding of Semaphore principle** 
I am currently trying to understand how Semaphores work.
I have understood that when calling P(sem), if sem=0 the thread will get blocked, otherwise the value of the semaphore will be reduced and the thread let into the critical section.
When calling V(sem), the semaphore value will be increased, if sem=0 and a thread is waiting, that thread is woken up.

**Now consider this problem:** 
Two threads are running, thread1 runs function1, thread2 runs function2. There are two semaphores s=0 and m=1 which are shared between both threads.

```
function1 {
    while(true) {
        P(s)
        P(s)
        P(m)
        print("a")
        V(m)
}}

function2 {
    while(true) {
        P(m)
        print("b")
        V(m)
        V(s)
}}
```

**What I expected would happen** 
I have expected the output string to be print b's and a's in some random order.

The threads start. Let's say thread1 enters function1 first: 
*Step1:* P(s)-> s=0 so block the thread 
thread2 enters function2 
P(m) -> m=1 -> set m=m-1=0 
**print b** 
V(m) -> m=m+1=1 
V(s) -> s=0 and thread is wating -> set s=s+1=1 and wake up thread

*Step2:* Thread2 returns to the **second** P-statement 
thread1 continues in function1 
P(s) -> s=1 -> set s=s-1=0 
P(m) -> m=1 -> set m=m-1=0 
**print a** 
V(m) -> m=0 but noone waiting -> set m=m+1=1

*Step2:* Thread1 runs function1 again 
P(s) -> s=0 -> block 
Thread2 runs function 2 
P(m) -> m=1 -> set m=m-1=0 
**print b**
V(m) -> m=m+1=1 
V(s) -> s=0 and thread waiting -> wake up thread 2

*Step3:* Thread1 returns to function1 second P-statement 
P(s) -> s=1 -> set s=s-1=0 
P(m) -> m=1 -> set m=m-1=0 
**print a** 
V(m) -> set m=1

*Step4* Thread2 runs function 2 
P(m) -> m=1 -> set m=0 
**print b**
V(m) -> set m=1 
V(s) -> s=0 -> set s=1, no thread waiting

*Step5* Thread 2 runs function 2 again 
**print b** 
... and so on

**The Problem/The Questions** 
I am very unsure, if it is correct, that thread1 returns to the second P-statement after it is woken up when thread2 runs function2. 
It seems wrong to me, because if I consider how a semaphore would usually be implemented:

```
P(s)
  * do something *
V(s)
```

If it where to return after the P-statement, the value of the semaphore does not get decreased, and the V-statement would increase the semaphore to a wrong value of 2. 
But if it repeats the first P-statement in the example, that would mean the output string is only b's.

Can someone tell me if my understanding is correct or if not, correct my mistake?

Comment: The thread being awoken returns from the `P()` method it is blocked in. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have implemented the problem in python and the output has the following pattern: b b a b b a b b a b b a

So I'm thinking, **when semaphore s=0 and is signaled with a thread waiting, it's value does not get incremented**. Instead it returns from the first wait-statement and executes the following statement. Is that the right behaviour?

Comment: " I have understood that when calling P(sem), if sem=0 the thread will get blocked, otherwise the value of the semaphore will be reduced" - You forgot to note, that after the thread will be unblocked the semaphore's value will be **reduced too**. That is, if some thread is blocked on a semaphore (while calling `P(sem)`), and another thread signals the semaphore (by using `V(sem)`), then **net change** of the semaphore's value will be 0: `V` will increment that value, but returning from `P` will decrement it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much! That explains it! I did not know that the value of the semaphore is reduced after a thread is unblocked, but of course that makes so much sense! Thank you for poinnting that out.